# Difference in access modifier handling between publish / publishLocal and compile / package

Tags: java, scala, sbt, private-members

In general Java doesn't respect Scala package `private` access modifiers. It means that `Bar`

```scala
package foo.bar

private[bar] case class Bar(x: String)
```

can be accessed from `Foo`

```java
package foo;

import foo.bar.Bar;

public class Foo {
  public static Bar bar() {
    return new Bar("bar");
  }
}
```

I created a simple package with the following structure:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   └── build.properties
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── foo
        │       └── Foo.java
        └── scala
            └── foo
                └── bar
                    └── Bar.scala
```

with `build.sbt` looking like this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
```

It can be compiled (`sbt compile`) and packaged (`sbt package`) and `Foo.bar` can be invoked from another project.

However it fails on `publish` / `publishLocal`:

```
sbt publishLocal
[info] Loading project definition from /path/to/source/project
[info] Loading settings for project simpleapp from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to simpleapp (in build file:/path/to/)
[info] Main Scala API documentation to /path/to/source/target/scala-2.12/api...
[info] Wrote /path/to/source/target/scala-2.12/simpleapp_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error] /path/to/source/src/main/java/foo/Foo.java:6:17: not found: type Bar
[error]   public static Bar bar() {
[error]                 ^
[info] No documentation generated with unsuccessful compiler run
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 1, 2019, 12:30:30 AM
```

I wonder if someone can explain this inconsistency, and if there is some workaround to make `publishLocal` in such case.

If that's relevant I use:

- SBT 1.3.4
- OpenJDK 11.0.5

*I am aware that the whole thing smells from a mile away, and I am perfectly fine with that for now.*

Comment: It looks like a bug in scaladoc compiler. As W/A you can disable it by adding the following settings in your `build.sbt`: `sources in (Compile, doc) := Nil`

Comment: Thank you @AndriyPlokhotnyuk, that's really helpful. I went with more precise approach, but around these lines. Would like to post it as an answer?

Comment: I would prefer to create some GitHub repo which reproduces your case and report the issue to https://github.com/scala/bug/issues and would asked guys from SBT if there is a better W/A: https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt